# `on` syntax generates duplication runs of an action

Tags: github-actions

I'd like an action that runs when we push **or** when then there is a PR to master.

The simple syntax would be `on: [push, pull_request]`.

However, when there is a PR to master from a branch, both events are triggered and two sets of the same action are started.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
```

It will trigger only when any PR is opened, when someone pushes new code to many PR and if any PR is re-opened